# Recuperar Childs Dinâmico no Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase

Estou com uma estrutura no firebase da seguinte forma. No app cliente quando a pessoa salva as informações, cria um child armazenado pelo número informado no campo celular (cria o child com o número de celular da pessoa). Se uma outra pessoa usar o app, quando essa outra pessoa salvar (cria um outro child com esse novo número que foi colocado no campo celular). Então temos dois childs de números diferentes.

Como posso recuperar esses valores no meu app de administrador, já que o child será dinâmico.

[image: Tenho dois numeros de teste no banco]

Esse código abaixo é onde eu recupero as informações e exibo em uma Listview. Se eu colocar assim `databaseReference.child("Pedidos").child("(99)99999-9999")` ele busca no banco e trás as informações desse número, até ai tudo bem, está funcionando. Porém eu estou colocando manualmente.

```
 databaseReference.child("Pedidos").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Pedido pd = new Pedido();

            listPedidosAdm.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot objSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                pd = objSnapshot.getValue(Pedido.class);
                listPedidosAdm.add(pd);
            }

            if (listPedidosAdm.size() <= 0) {
                Toast.makeText(AdmPedidosActivity.this, "Não há nenhum pedido",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {

                AdapterPersonalizadoAdm adapter = new AdapterPersonalizadoAdm(listPedidosAdm,
                        AdmPedidosActivity.this);

                listview_AdmPedidos.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: pq tu não usa a key como referência ao invés do número de telefone?